# Volume is not mounted even when pvc is created

Tags: kubernetes

I am using helm chart for the installation of the application, the volume is not mounted. I am doing something wrong but not sure what is it. I am new to devops

**values.yaml**

```
persistence:
  enabled: true
  existingClaim: grafana-persistent-storage
  mountPath: "/dev/grafana/"
```

**pvc.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: grafana-block-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Block
  storageClassName: grafana-persistent-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

**storageClass.yaml**

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: grafana-persistent-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  iopsPerGB: "10"
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

PVC is creaed

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=<configfile> get pvc -n grafana
NAME                STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS                 AGE
grafana-block-pvc   Bound    pvc-6dc39e0d-471e-11ea-b432-0a505018290a   10Gi       RWO            grafana-persistent-storage   10m
```

PV created too

```
pvc-6dc39e0d-471e-11ea-b432-0a505018290a   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound      grafana/grafana-block-pvc               grafana-persistent-storage            10m
```

**Kubectl describe pod** - the description of the pod created.

```
Name:           grafana1-v1-79fb988995-lnnl6
Namespace:      grafana
Priority:       0
Node:           ip-10-10-108-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal/10.10.108.165
Start Time:     Tue, 04 Feb 2020 13:15:17 +0530
Labels:         app.kubernetes.io/instance=grafana1
                app.kubernetes.io/name=grafana1
                pod-template-hash=79fb988995
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
                sidecar.istio.io/status:
                  {"version":"761ebc53976754715f22fcf548f05270fb4b8db07324894aebdb31fa81d960","initContainers":["istio-init"],"containers":["istio-proxy"]...
Status:         Running
IP:             10.10.127.38
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/grafana1-v1-79fb988995
Init Containers:
  istio-init:
    Container ID:  docker://a95db52c5b45c8147fb6c6d0ce4013bef6d495752dc820565188032bc36926
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxy_init:1.2.5
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://istio/proxy_init@sha256:c9964a8c28b85cc631bbc90390eac238c90f82c8f929495d1e9f9a9135b724
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      -p
      15001
      -u
      1337
      -m
      REDIRECT
      -i
      *
      -x

      -b
      3000
      -d
      15020
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 04 Feb 2020 13:15:18 +0530
      Finished:     Tue, 04 Feb 2020 13:15:19 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  50Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        10m
      memory:     10Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
Containers:
  grafana1:
    Container ID:   docker://92338e43bbf69a2c0919e81f5ae16948e6f7966353a3db52274a5a14902599
    Image:          grafana/grafana:latest
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://grafana/grafana@sha256:4319ca3e5592ee408f5842ce5b5955312549d89dc1572d2543f2f6d67ca619
    Port:           3000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 04 Feb 2020 13:15:23 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  200Mi
    Environment:
      GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD:  deskera@reports
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-99rfk (ro)
  istio-proxy:
    Container ID:  docker://21b965ec954474b3bcb941a20782f99642f002bb0e9a212aed20e19838c2f0
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.2.5
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://istio/proxyv2@sha256:8f210c3d09beb6b8658a55d9ac30e25549295834a44083ed67d652ad7453e4
    Port:          15090/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      proxy
      sidecar
      --domain
      $(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
      --configPath
      /etc/istio/proxy
      --binaryPath
      /usr/local/bin/envoy
      --serviceCluster
      istio-proxy.grafana
      --drainDuration
      45s
      --parentShutdownDuration
      1m0s
      --discoveryAddress
      istio-pilot.istio-system:15010
      --zipkinAddress
      zipkin.istio-system:9411
      --dnsRefreshRate
      300s
      --connectTimeout
      10s
      --proxyAdminPort
      15000
      --concurrency
      2
      --controlPlaneAuthPolicy
      NONE
      --statusPort
      15020
      --applicationPorts
      3000
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 04 Feb 2020 13:15:23 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   128Mi
    Readiness:  http-get http://:15020/healthz/ready delay=1s timeout=1s period=2s #success=1 #failure=30
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:                          grafana1-v1-79fb988995-lnnl6 (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:                     grafana (v1:metadata.namespace)
      INSTANCE_IP:                        (v1:status.podIP)
      ISTIO_META_POD_NAME:               grafana1-v1-79fb988995-lnnl6 (v1:metadata.name)
      ISTIO_META_CONFIG_NAMESPACE:       grafana (v1:metadata.namespace)
      ISTIO_META_INTERCEPTION_MODE:      REDIRECT
      ISTIO_META_INCLUDE_INBOUND_PORTS:  3000
      ISTIO_METAJSON_ANNOTATIONS:        {"kubernetes.io/psp":"eks.privileged"}

      ISTIO_METAJSON_LABELS:             {"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"grafana1","app.kubernetes.io/name":"grafana1","pod-template-hash":"79fb988995"}

    Mounts:
      /etc/certs/ from istio-certs (ro)
      /etc/istio/proxy from istio-envoy (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-99rfk (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-99rfk:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-99rfk
    Optional:    false
  istio-envoy:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     Memory
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  istio-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  istio.default
    Optional:    true
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                                                       Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                                                       -------
  Normal  Scheduled  13m   default-scheduler                                          Successfully assigned grafana/grafana1-v1-79fb988995-lnnl6 to ip-10-10-108-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
  Normal  Pulled     13m   kubelet, ip-10-10-108-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Container image "docker.io/istio/proxy_init:1.2.5" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    13m   kubelet, ip-10-10-108-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Created container istio-init
  Normal  Started    13m   kubelet, ip-10-10-108-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Started container istio-init
  Normal  Pulling    13m   kubelet, ip-10-10-108-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Pulling image "grafana/grafana:latest"
  Normal  Pulled     13m   kubelet, ip-10-10-108-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Successfully pulled image "grafana/grafana:latest"
  Normal  Created    13m   kubelet, ip-10-10-108-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Created container grafana1
  Normal  Started    13m   kubelet, ip-10-10-108-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Started container grafana1
  Normal  Pulled     13m   kubelet, ip-10-10-108-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Container image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.2.5" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    13m   kubelet, ip-10-10-108-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Created container istio-proxy
  Normal  Started    13m   kubelet, ip-10-10-108-165.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Started container istio-proxy
```

Please refer the describe part of the pod. The volume is still not mounted even after changing the existing claim to pvc

Comment: Where are you running this? Is it EKS?

Answer (score 0):

```
persistence:
  enabled: true
  existingClaim: grafana-block-pvc
  mountPath: "/dev/grafana/"
```

Claim name should be `grafana-block-pvc`  rather than `grafana-persistent-storage` in your values.yaml

Comment: Can you run `kubectl describe pod $POD_NAME` ?

Comment: Btw, you are mounting a block device, not the file system

Comment: Yes, am monting the block not file. Please refer edited question for the description of pod

Comment: I do not see any reference of pvc in volume section. is the helm chart public ?

Comment: No, its not public, I am sure I might be missing something. But I am new to this, can you help me how to fix this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207155/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-kapil-gupta).

Comment: Can we continue on chat.